# Could someone explain how arrays inside of objects work? What is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and i decided to make a game to practice, and i immediately ran into problems. This is my code. I think it explains itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var user = {
            name: this.name,
            species: this.species,
            stats: [this.strength=0, this.wit=0, this.magic=0, this.health=0]
        }
        user.name = prompt("What is your name?");
        user.species = prompt("Hello, " + user.name + ". What is your species? Orc, Human, Elf, Troll, or Mage.");
        user.species = user.species.toLowerCase;
        //Sets the stats according to what the user said
        switch(user.species){
            case "orc":
                user.stats=[user.strength=4, user.wit=2, user.magic=2, user.health=45];
                break;
            case "human":
                user.stats=[user.strength=3, user.wit=3, user.magic=3, user.health=40];
                break;
            case "troll":
                user.stats=[user.strength=5, user.wit=1, user.magic=1, user.health=50];
                break;
            case "elf":
                user.stats=[user.strength=3, user.wit=4, user.magic=3, user.health=35];
                break;
            case "mage":
                user.stats=[user.strength=3, user.wit=4, user.magic=3, user.health=30];                                                         
                break;
        }
        //It is supposed to output the strength
        document.write(user.stats[0]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is no matter what I enter it always prints "0".
Could someone please explain the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this: `stats: [this.strength=0, this.wit=0, this.magic=0, this.health=0]` because this looks very unusual and is likely not doing what you want and would likely create an error in strict mode.  In fact, your whole `user` data declaration looks like wrong use of `this`.

Comment: I recommend doing a Javascript Object Orientated programming course to get the basics down you should check out Code School, they have some great free beginner content.

Answer (score 2):

`user.species.toLowerCase` needs to be `user.species.toLowerCase()`. By not calling the function you assign the function to user.species and thus it never matches any of the cases. You should also add a `default` case to catch these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with -

```
user.species = user.species.toLowerCase();
```

toLowerCase is a function.

Reference - [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp](http://tolowercase%20function)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing () on user.species = user.species.toLowerCase;